# Is it possible to redirected to my own domain (without registered) from my sub domain?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, server

Is it possible to redirected to my own domain (without registered) from my sub domain?

I have sales.example.com this name is so hard to marketing. So I willing to show this as mysaleexample.com.

Note: here I have not purchase this domain mysaleexample.com, I need it victual call only but I show the content form sales.example.com

I dont want to purchase multiple domain. Using the example.com domain i need vitual call domain by using .htaccess file..

Comment: You can't control what's in `mysaleexample.com` for other people without registering it first (if I understand what you are trying to do).

Comment: ok.. But can you tell me how to do that using .htaccess file?

Comment: You have to register the domain (and you can't do it with .htaccess).  Domains loaded in the browser are redirected to the worldwide domain name system, which is where you decide where then leads by registering and setting up DNS records, you can't go the other way.

Comment: Oh ok thanks a lot